# UITableView Pagination for API request results, Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, api, uitableview, pagination

I'm making a newsreader app that shows list of news (title, image, description). I successfully get data from the API, and I need to make pagination showing 15 results per request. I've already added a pageSize parameter to API URL. Please help me out. This is a fetch articles function:

````
self.articles = [Article]()
     do {
       let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

                if let articlesFromJson = json["articles"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for articlesFromJson in articlesFromJson {
                        let article = Article()
                        if
                            let title = articlesFromJson["title"] as? String,
                            let urlToImage = articlesFromJson["urlToImage"] as? String,
                            let description = articlesFromJson["description"] as? String,

                        {
                            article.headline = title
                            article.imageUrl = urlToImage
                            article.desc = description
                        }

                        self.articles?.append(article)  
                    }
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.newsList.reloadData()

                }```
````

Comment: How many results are you getting from API?

Comment: I get 20 results as it's a default value given from NewsAPI.org

Comment: so as the user scroll you can get request for more results or you want to do something else

Comment: Right, i'd like to get more results...So user opens the app, scrolls through 15 articles, reaches to the bottom and gets another 15 articles.

Comment: Now you can do 2 things---1. Add a Footer view show activity indicator and call API. 2. Call API when you reach 10, 20, 30, so on and fetch next results